# Kotlin accessing an abstract function in a non abstract function in abstract class

Tags: object, kotlin, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a class that is basically this:

```
abstract class BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction {

    // Invoke should compute some function, like f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 5
    abstract fun invoke(x: List<Double>): Double

    // This is supposed to return an object deriving this one where 
    // invoke actually returns 1/(1+f(x)), essentially reversing the function.
    fun reverse(): BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction =
            object: BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction() {
                override operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>): Double {
                    var denominator = 1.0 + super.invoke(x)
                    if (denominator.absoluteValue < Double.MIN_VALUE * 10)
                        denominator += denominator.sign * Double.MIN_VALUE * 10

                    return 1.0 / denominator
                }
            }
}
```

Problem is that `invoke` is abstract so the compiler complains that `Abstract member cannot be accessed directly.` which is true.

However any class deriving my class will obviously be forced to implement `invoke` so conceptually there should no problem with calling `reverse` in those classes but having the implementation in this base class. The implementation of `reverse` while strictly speaking *is dependent* on `invoke`, this implementation can not be called in any class that does not also provide an `invoke` anyway.

The simplest solution is to duplicate the code for `reverse` in every class but i'd rather not have code duplication.

So my question is what exactly is an elegant way of doing what I want: providing a well-defined behaviour (`reverse`) that uses behaviour not defined yet (`invoke`) but that will 100% be defined at the time when `reverse` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `super.invoke(x)` is trying to call the super method of the object that derives directly from `BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction`.  Since there's no super implementation, you get the error.  You probably want to hold a reference to the original function:

```kotlin
    fun reverse(): BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction {
        val originalFunction = this
        return object: BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction() {
            override operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>): Double {
                var denominator = 1.0 + originalFunction.invoke(x)
                if (denominator.absoluteValue < Double.MIN_VALUE * 10)
                    denominator += denominator.sign * Double.MIN_VALUE * 10

                return 1.0 / denominator
            }
        }
    }
```